# Equation with matrix and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given

$$A={\begin{bmatrix}
\det(A)  &  \det(A)+a \\
\det(A) +b & \det(A)+c
\end{bmatrix}}$$

where $a,b,c$ are given and $A$ is unknown, is it possible to use some clever tricks concerning determinants for this case? (instead of direct calculations).

Comment: What *equation*? That's only a matrix...or did you mean to evaluate the determinant of the matrix $\;A\;$ ? Are $\;a,b,c,d\;$ the matrix $\,A\,'$ s entries?

Comment: I have $\det A = \frac{ab}{c-a-b-1}$.

Comment: The determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix is simple enough. It probably takes more time to figure out a clever trick (if there is one) then just get your hands dirty ( set $t = \det A$, compute the determinant of resulting matrix, match it against $t$ and solve for $t$)

Comment: @DonAntonio matrix $A$ is unknown.. of course if we find $\det(A)$ we find also $A$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\text{det}A=d$. Then we are given
$$A={\begin{bmatrix}
d  &  d+a \\
d +b & d+c
\end{bmatrix}}$$
Using row operations, we get
$$
d=|A|=\begin{vmatrix}
d  &  d+a \\
d +b & d+c
\end{vmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{vmatrix}
d  &  d+a \\
b & c-a
\end{vmatrix}
\rightarrow \begin{vmatrix}
d  &  a \\
b & c-a-b
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Thus 
$$d=d(c-a-b)-ab.$$
Now solve for $d$.

Comment: ok, so it seems that row operations give fast answer..

Comment: @Widawensen I did use the row operation but honestly speaking row operations is an overkill. You could have simply used determinant $d=(d(d+c))-(d+a)(d+b)$ to get to the answer.

Comment: so case 2x2 is simple, case for 3x3 matrix would be probably a little more complicated ..

Comment: @Widawensen Yes perhaps there row operations will be more useful.

Comment: I wonder whether there is a general method for n x n ..

Comment: It is worth noticing that for some $a,b,c$ there is no solution...

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$\mathrm A = \det(\mathrm A) \, 1_2 1_2^{\top} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a\\ b & c\end{bmatrix}$$

Assuming that $a b \neq 0$ and using the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma),

$$\begin{array}{rl} \det(\mathrm A) &= \left( 1 + \det(\mathrm A) 1_2^{\top} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a\\ b & c\end{bmatrix}^{-1} 1_2 \right) \det \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a\\ b & c\end{bmatrix}\\ &= \left( 1 - \frac{\det(\mathrm A)}{a b} 1_2^{\top} \begin{bmatrix} c & -a\\ -b & 0\end{bmatrix} 1_2 \right) (- a b)\\ &= - a b + \det(\mathrm A) 1_2^{\top} \begin{bmatrix} c & -a\\ -b & 0\end{bmatrix} 1_2\\ &= (c - a - b) \det(\mathrm A) - a b\end{array}$$

Comment: Fantastic answer :).. thank you Rodrigo for sharing it with all users,,.. and it has evident advantage that it can be generalized . .. It should be the most important however I choose the other earlier (also very interesting) .. I hope that other users also appreciate your ingenuity.. this is the answer from these with the greatest value - it extends the knowledge of the asking person..

Comment: Now, thanks to Rodrigo, generalization is possible for  

$$A_{n{\times}n}={\begin{bmatrix}
\det(A)+d_{11}  & \cdots & \det(A)+d_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\det(A) +d_{n1} & \cdots& \det(A)+d_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}}$$ where $d_{ij}$ are given.

Comment: @Widawensen Just make sure that the $[d_{ij}]$ matrix is invertible.